# Implementation of Straight Skeleton with Simple Polygon

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, polygons

I have been trying to find an easy to understand straight skeleton implementation for a simple, concaved, polygon with holes. The best paper I can find on this is: http://www.dma.fi.upm.es/personal/mabellanas/tfcs/skeleton/html/documentacion/Straight%20Skeletons%20Implementation.pdf

However, I got quite confused with the flow of the algorithm. Let just consider the easier case: a convex polygon.

1. In step 1c, after finding out the nearer bisector intersection, the author store that intersection into a priority queue, according to the distance to the line that contains edge $e_i$. My question is, does this mean EVERY edge will have a priority queue? If this is not the case, what is $e_i$ that the author referred to?
2. In step 2, and I assuming that every edge would have a priority queue, which edge does the author start with first? And when the author mentioned "continue on the step 2", does that mean continue the current loop iteration or move to the next iteration?

On that note, if anyone know a similar algorithm that has been implemented in Matlab, that would be great too.

Comment: Have you implemented this algorithm and would be willing to release it under a free license?
I am planing to implement DOI 10.1142/S0218654308001051 for slice interpolation and finding the straight skeleton is one of the steps. Would be great if I didn't have to reimplement it.

Comment: @mcandril Hi. I gave up on implementing it, since there were too many edge cases. It was a good learning experience nonetheless. Anyways, I suggest you check out CGAL, which is the gold standard for computational geometry. What kind of programming language you are familiar with?

Comment: C++, Python, MATLAB. Thanks. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1$. It's a single priority queue. a) Because there are at most two bisectors per vertex and it wouldn't make sense to have a priority queue for at most two items. b) Because step $2$ speaks of “the priority queue” without referring to an edge. The edge $e_i$ referred to in step $1 (c)$ is defined in step $1 (b)$.

$2$. This is badly phrased. From the fact that step $2 (c)$ outputs three skeleton arcs before “continuing on the step $2$” and step $2 (d)$ would output two of those again, it seems that “continue” here is meant in the sense in which it's used in some programming languages, namely, start the next iteration of step $2$ from the top instead of moving on to step $2(d)$; but I'm not $100\%$ sure about that one.

Comment: Huh, that's clear things up quite a bit. Thanks!

But what about the case with multiple LAVs (polygon with holes, or with split events), is the number of priority queues still remains one, or one for each LAV? Thanks again.

Comment: @AnhTran: In the first paragraph of Section $2.2$, where the case of multiple LAVs is treated ("all LAVs"), it still says “the priority queue” with a definite article, so there seems to be still only one priority queue. Admittedly, the paper is obviously written by non-native speakers in quite bad English, so we can't be sure they didn't know how to use articles correctly; but if we take it at face value, that's what it says.

Comment: I think that's the correct way to look at it. I have been making some progress in term of implementation of the algorithm (thanks!), and now I'm moving towards non-convex polygons. However, some are quite confusing. 


1. For step 2c (non-convex), the authors said that it is similar to convex case. However, in convex case, an intersection is linked to 2 other vertexes, which is then used to determine "top of the roof" skeleton. A reflex intersection is only linked to 1 vertex, so how would you go about doing the same thing?

Comment: 2. For dot point 3 of step 2e, the authors "search" the opposite edge. Why would they "search" for the opposite edge, meanwhile in convex case, the edge is already linked to the intersection I (no need to search).

Comment: p/s: merry christmas, joriki.